# Why does a locomotive pantograph arc when lowered even though the circuit breaker is "open"?

Tags: high-voltage, overhead-lines

Why does a locomotive pantograph arc when lowered even though the circuit breaker is "open"?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this is the sort of thing that will vary by the equipment being used.  You may want to _edit your question_ to say what country and time you saw this, and if you know it, say what manufacturer and model of locomotive it is (or include a picture in your question).  One certainly _could_ design an electric locomotive that didn't do this.

Comment: @TimWescott 25kV AC line... the electrical capacity of the disconnected pantograph is enough to make a visible spark. Lower voltage systems could probably avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that the circuit breaker is actually open if there are sparks when the pantograph is disconnected. [Here](https://studyelectrical.com/2014/05/how-electric-locomotives-work.html) is a pretty good explanation and block diagram for a modern electric locomotive.

[image: Electric locomotive]

[Here is a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNBhwo3yT_E) with perhaps a bit more detail about the circuit breaker. But it appears to be used primarily for overcurrent or other failure.

Answer (score 0):

Because the circuit breaker is *not* open.